# loop through objects inside an array in a regex

Tags: arrays, regex, loops, object

**EDITED**

I got an array of objects:

```
values: [
          { key: "CollinHenderson" },
          { key: "SarahDrasner" },
          { key: "EvanYou" },
          { key: "AdamWathan" }
        ]
```

I want to highlight the text if one of them is mentioned ("@..."):

```
.innerHTML
    .replace(
      /(?:|^)@[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.\\__äÄöÖüÜß]+(?:|$)/g,
      "<span  contenteditable='false' class='markAt'>$&</span>"
    );
```

with this regex (above) everything gets highlighted which starts with a '@'. How could I loop trough my array of objects inside of my regex, so that it only turns out true if one of my users get mentioned. For Example: 
"@hello" should be false  
"@CollinHenderson" should be true and get therefore highlighted

```
/(?:|^)@[  //loop through array - if matches a value -> true // ]+(?:|$)/g,
```

Comment: The array of objects in your code isn't a good example, please provide an input that has at least one `@` and then post an example of what you expect the results to be. Then post the code you tried using to get these results. Then post what you got as a result (what you didn't expect as a result of your broken code) Provide all of this as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to replace and check in there

```js
const values = [{
    key: "CollinHenderson"
  },
  {
    key: "SarahDrasner"
  },
  {
    key: "EvanYou"
  },
  {
    key: "AdamWathan"
  }
]

const el = document.getElementById('foo');

el.addEventListener('keyup', e => {

  document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = e.target.value
    .replace(
      /(?:|^)@[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.\\__äÄöÖüÜß]+(?:|$)/g,
      m => {
        if (values.find(v => m.substring(1) === v.key)) return "<span  contenteditable='false' class='markAt'>"+ m + "</span>";
       return m;
      }
    );
});
```

```css
.markAt {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
<div id="bar">

</div>
```